# unisigned char right shift to 8 bits getting warning

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++

```
psApdu->ble>>8
```

when i compile this statement in visual studio,

```
errorC220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated.

warning C4333: '>>' right shift by too large amount, data loss
```

Why this ***warning***?

info: `ble` is an `unsigned char` field of structure `psApdu`

Comment: How are you sure that the warning corresponds to the shifting operation?

Comment: if i change **psApdu->ble>>7** like this, no warning!

Comment: After your edit, your question makes sense and contains the answer too

Comment: Are you using /WX option?  Disable it and post results.  Different message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's oh-so-subtly trying to point out that taking an 8-bit quantity and right-shifting it 8 bits leaves nothing of the input, so the result isn't likely to be of a lot of use as a rule.

Comment: But note that the behavior, though it's not terribly useful, is still well defined.  If the right operand of a shift operator is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined -- but an `unsigned char` operand will first be promoted to int (or, unlikely, to unsigned int).  Still, it's a perfectly reasonable warning; you might as well replace `psApdu->ble>>8` with `0`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Right -- if you shift by more bits than the promoted type, then you get a different (though, of course, similar) warning: `warning C4293: '>>' : shift count negative or too big, undefined behavior`